# JPA Criteria builder IN clause query

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0, openjpa

How to write criteria builder api query for below given JPQL query?
I am using `JPA 2.2`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.Parent IN ('John','Raj')
ORDER BY e.Parent
```

Comment: Check out here: plenty of examples of various criteria, including IN: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries

Answer (score 93):

This criteria set-up should do the trick:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> q = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);


Root<Employee> root = q.from(Employee.class);
q.select(root);

List<String> parentList = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"John", "Raj"});

Expression<String> parentExpression = root.get(Employee_.Parent);
Predicate parentPredicate = parentExpression.in(parentList);
q.where(parentPredicate);
q.orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(Employee_.Parent));

q.getResultList();
```

I have used the overloaded `CriteriaQuery.where` method here which accepts a `Predicate`.. an `in` predicate in this case.

Comment: where do u get the Employee_ from

Comment: Employee_ is the Metamodel of the class Employee https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html

Comment: Note that since Java Persistence 2.0 `Predicate` is used instead of `Expression` in `javax.persistence.criteria` API in order to work around the fact that Java generics are not compatible with varags.

Answer (score 15):

You can also do this with Criteria API In clause as below:

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Employee> cq = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
Root<Employee> root = cq.from(Employee.class);
List<String> parentList = Arrays.asList("John", "Raj");
In<String> in = cb.in(root.get(Employee_parent));
parentList.forEach(p -> in.value(p));

return entityManager
        .createQuery(cq.select(root)
        .where(in).orderBy(cb.asc(root.get(Employee_.Parent)))
        .getResultList();
```

Checkout my [Github](https://github.com/vaneetkataria/Jpa-Hibernate/blob/master/jdbcToJpaMigration/src/test/java/com/katariasoft/technologies/jpaHibernate/entity/criteria/SingleTableCriteriaFetchTests.java) for this and almost all possible criteria examples.

Answer (score 11):

```
List<String> parentList = Arrays.asList("John", "Raj");            
final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Employee> query = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
final Root<Employee> employee = query.from(Employee.class);

query.select(employee).where(employee.get("Parent").in(parentList));
```

this should work fine. for more info please refer this article by baeldung. it is very resourceful https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-criteria-api-in-expressions

Comment: I usually prefer the typesafe variant as this prevents error after refactoring an attribute name.

Answer (score 4):

I hope it could be useful. The code tested in case when Entry has only one @Id column:

```
public static <Entry, Id> List<Entry> getByIds(List<Id> ids, Class<Entry> clazz, EntityManager entityManager) throws CustomDatabaseException
{
    List<Entry> entries;
    try
    {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Entry> q = cb.createQuery(clazz);
        Root<Entry> root = q.from(clazz);
        EntityType<Entry> e = root.getModel();
        CriteriaQuery<Entry> all = q.where(root.get(e.getId(e.getIdType().getJavaType()).getName()).in(ids));

        TypedQuery<Entry> allQuery = entityManager.createQuery(all);
        entries = allQuery.getResultList();
    }
    catch (NoResultException nre)
    {
        entries = Collections.emptyList()
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new CustomDatabaseException(e);
    }
    return entries;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to break your head when you need to do this again using Criteria API - you can create a **parent wrapper class** for your Dao and put a **hepler method** there:

```
/**
  * An SQL "WHERE IN" expression alternative.
  *
  * @param inList List to search in.
  * @param pathToEntityField Path to a field in your entity object.
  * @return A ready predicate-condition to paste into CriteriaQuery.where().
  */
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 private Predicate in(List<?> inList, Expression pathToEntityField) {

   return pathToEntityField.in(inList);
}
```

Use WHERE IN then like:

```
query.where(**in**(myList, root.get(MyTypedEntity_.id)));
```