# JPA Criteria - How to prepare a SELECT IN query

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a rather simple SQL query where I need to get data from a Parent table based on a query on another Child table. For example:

Parent table:

```
ID NAME
-- ----
22 Frederick
26 James
39 Robert
```

Child table:

```
PARENT_ID NAME
--------- ----
22        Joey
22        Cindy
26        Robbie
39        Joe
```

So I need an SQL query like this that would get the names of any parents who have a child with a name like *Joe* - i.e., Frederick and Robert.

```
select NAME from PARENTS where ID in (
  select PARENT_ID from CHILDREN where NAME like '%Joe%'
);
```

I'm trying something like this:

```
Subquery<Child> childSubquery = criteriaQuery.subquery(Child.class);
Root<Child> childRoot = childSubquery.from(Child.class);
Predicate likeChild = criteriaBuilder.like(childRoot.get(Child_.name), '%Joe%');
```

This would get me the children with names like *Joe*.

So how do I then get the parents of those children?

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530677/jpa-criteria-builder-in-clause-query/42531461#42531461), I tried like this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Parent> parentQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Parent.class);
Root<Parent> parentRoot = parentQuery.from(Parent.class);
parentQuery.select(parentRoot);
parentQuery.where(likeChild);
parentQuery.getResultList() <--- this method doesn't exist in CriteriaQuery!!
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530677/jpa-criteria-builder-in-clause-query/42531461#42531461

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Thanks for the link.. I actually looked at that answer, but I couldn't see how to match them up. For example, in that answer, the parentList is simply hard-coded as an array. In my case, the parentList is a Predicate from another query.