# Hibernate - CriteriaBuilder does collection contain any element of filter collection

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a following field in my Entity:

```
    @ElementCollection(targetClass = UserType.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_type", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Column(name = "ttype", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)    
    public Set<UserType> getUserTypes() {
        return userTypes;
    }

    public void setUserTypes(Set<UserType> userTypes) {
        this.userTypes = userTypes;
    }
```

This fetches collection of user types assigned to particular user. This works fine. Now I need to filter users who are members of { ADMIN, MANAGER } types. So I need to get users who are type of any of type provided in filter.

So I tried

```
queryRoot.get("userTypes").in(filterTypes)
```

But this obviously does not work. Seems like CriteriaBuilder provides basic comparison functions like `equals`, `ge`, etc. But for this check there is nothing.

How to make such query via CriteriaBuilder?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA Criteria builder IN clause query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530677/jpa-criteria-builder-in-clause-query)

Comment: unfortunately no. I need to check whether Set from database contain any property from filter Set.

Comment: `So I need to get users who are type of any of type provided in filter`. That is exactly what the `in` clause is for. You pass in a list of acceptable values and only those will be returned form database. Also it help to post your whole code

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: I am wondering if `isMember` does the trick, but cannot find good example how to use it.

Comment: but filter can contain many types not just single one.

Comment: That is why you use `in` and not `eq`...