# Query if a array column contains using Criteria

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table named `users` with a column `groupIDs` which is list of `Long` type.

Can I create a query using `Criteria` so that select all users which have a given groupID in it's `groupIDs` column. I am using Spring boot and PostgreSQL.

I need result something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE groupID IN groupIDs
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more of your code? E.g. the `User` entity and its relation with groupsIds?

Comment: @pleft Sorry, I am not allowed to share code, but UserEntity has just a list that contains Long values representing groups they are part of, and there is no other connection implemented.

Comment: You can't share `private List<Long> groupIDs`? Does this property has an annotation over it? like `@OneToMany` ? You can share such small details without exposing your full code.

Comment: Your SQL Query in your question does not reflect what you describe: *Can I create a query using Criteria so that select all users which have a given groupID in it's groupIDs column*. -> This is not an "IN" query. In an "IN" query the input parameter is the **list** whereas in your description the input parameter is the **specific groupId**. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list parameters.

Sql Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE groupID IN (:groupIds)
```

Then assign parameters:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("groupIds",Arrays.asList(1l,2l....));
dao.query(sql,params);
```

For changing to Criteria, refer to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42531461/1439560