# where clause queryString giving SQL Error: 920, SQLState: 42000 in Oracle DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, oracle11g

I have below code trying to fetch some data from Oracle DB tableName based on post request sent.

I form query queryString using all post request inputs by appending over a loop, then send this queryString as whereClause parameter to Query in repository class.

```
POST REQUEST:

{
  "list": ["002-02-0284","029-00-0100"]
}

@PostMapping(“/fetch”)
fun sync(@RequestBody @Valid DataRequest: request): ResponseEntity<SyncResponse> {

   val list = request.list

   return ResponseEntity(service.getContainers(list), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
}


  fun getContainers(list: List<String>){

  val conditions = mutableListOf<String>()

  for (item in list) {
    val values = extractValues(item)
    val departmentId = values[0]
    val classId = values[1]
    val itemId = values[2]
    conditions.add("(DEPT_I = :departmentId AND CLASS_I = :classId AND ITEM_I = :itemId)")
  }

   val whereClause = conditions.joinToString(" OR ")

   println("--< whereClause --> $whereClause")

   val responseList = service.getContainers(whereClause)
 }

  fun extractValues(item: String): Array<Int> {
     return item.split("-").map { it.toInt() }.toTypedArray()
  }

  fun getContainers(whereClause: String): List<yourClass> {
    return repository.getContainers(queryString)
  }

@Query(
nativeQuery = true,
value = "SELECT PALT_I " +
    "FROM tableName " +
    "WHERE (:whereClause) AND STAT_C NOT IN ('PL', 'CN') " +
    "ORDER BY PALT_I "
  )
  fun getContainers(
  @param("whereClause") whereClause: String): List<tableName>
```

I am seeing error as below

Hibernate: SELECT PALT_I, SIZE_C, AREA_C, DEPT_I, CLASS_I, ITEM_I, AISLE_I, BIN_I, LVL_I, PALT_UNIT_Q, AVAIL_PALT_UNIT_Q, PALT_PEND_POST_Q,PALT_PEND_PULL_Q, PALT_PEND_PTWY_Q, PULL_PALT_UNIT_Q, VCP_Q, SSP_Q, PALT_Q, CTN_PER_PALT_Q, EXPIRE_D, LOT_I, HOLD_STAT_C, STAT_C, MODF_USER_ID, MODF_PGM_N, MODF_TS FROM RSV_PALT WHERE (?) AND STAT_C NOT IN ('PL', 'CN') ORDER BY PALT_I

Hibernate: select inventoryi0_.container_id as container_id1_6_0_, inventoryi0_.update_timestamp as update_timestamp2_6_0_ from inventory_in_progress inventoryi0_ where inventoryi0_.container_id=?
Hibernate: select inventoryi0_.container_id as container_id1_6_0_, inventoryi0_.update_timestamp as update_timestamp2_6_0_ from inventory_in_progress inventoryi0_ where inventoryi0_.container_id=?

[WARN] 2023-11-22 11:25:42,993 http-nio-8080-exec-1 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - {X-API-ID=3283db6f-ef50-4d04-be5b-45ed5751432d, X-CORRELATION-ID=3283db6f-ef50-4d04-be5b-45ed5751432d, team=Ole} - **SQL Error: 920, SQLState: 42000**

[ERROR] 2023-11-22 11:25:42,994 http-nio-8080-exec-1 org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - {X-API-ID=3283db6f-ef50-4d04-be5b-45ed5751432d, X-CORRELATION-ID=3283db6f-ef50-4d04-be5b-45ed5751432d, team=Ole} - **ORA-00920: invalid relational operator**

any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the query using:

```java
@Query(
  nativeQuery = true,
  value = "SELECT PALT_I " +
          "FROM RSV_PALT " +
          "WHERE (:whereClause) AND STAT_C NOT IN ('PL', 'CN') " +
          "ORDER BY PALT_I "
)
fun getContainers(
  @Param("whereClause") whereClause: String
): List<TableName>
```

The bind variable `:whereClause` is a placeholder for a single scalar value which is passed directly to the database and is not used to build the query as part of a template string.

Therefore, when the database evaluates the string it is the equivalent of evaluating:

```sql
SELECT PALT_I
FROM   RSV_PALT
WHERE  ('some text')
AND    STAT_C NOT IN ('PL', 'CN')
ORDER BY PALT_I
```

and `WHERE ('some text')` is an invalid SQL expression as it is missing a relational operator because the database is expecting `WHERE ('some text' = 'some other text')`.

To fix it you need to generate the dynamic query text as part of the string and use bind variables to pass only values into the query and not trying to add the dynamic part of the query using bind variables.

Something like:

```java
@Query(
  nativeQuery = true,
  value = "SELECT PALT_I " +
          "FROM   RSV_PALT " +
          "WHERE  (DEPT_I = :departmentId OR :departmentId IS NULL) " +
          "AND    (CLASS_I = :classId OR :classId IS NULL) " +
          "AND    (ITEM_I = :itemId OR :itemId IS NULL) "+
          "AND    STAT_C NOT IN ('PL', 'CN') " +
          "ORDER BY PALT_I "
)
```

and then always pass `departmentId`, `classId` and `itemId` into the query but pass `NULL` values when you do not want to filter on them.

Comment: got you.. but is there anyway in jpa query ? or something like below would help ?        
 SELECT * FROM RSV_PALT rp  WHERE ( lpad(DEPT_I,3,0) ||'-'||lpad(CLASS_I,2,0)||'-'||lpad(ITEM_I,4,0)  ) IN  ('002-02-0284','029-00-0100')

Comment: @user3534759 I mostly do Oracle and not Spring/JPA so I can tell you why you are getting the error but you really need a Spring expert to give you the best solution. You can search the internet for `jpa sql in expression` which may lead you to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42530677/1509264). In Oracle, you could also do: `WHERE (dept_i, class_i, item_i) IN ((2,2,284), (29,0,100))` but I'm not sure if Spring/JPA supports binding values to `IN` expressions with multiple terms.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a way to do it.

```
@Repository
open class RepositoryClass @Autowired constructor(
private val entityManager: EntityManager) {

open fun getContainers(whereClause: String): List<yourClass> {
    val nativeQuery = """
        SELECT PALT_I
        FROM tableName
        WHERE STAT_C NOT IN ('A', 'B')
        AND $whereClause
        ORDER BY PALT_I
    """.trimIndent()

    return entityManager.createNativeQuery(nativeQuery, yourClass::class.java).resultList as List<yourClass>
}
```

}